# Perform calculation in .launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I wondered if it is possible to do a calculation in a roslaunch file, something like:

```
<arg name="windowsize" default="20"/>

<node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen" clear_params="true">
    <param name="xmin" value="$(arg -windowsize/2)" />
    <param name="ymin" value="$(arg  -windowsize/2)" />
    <param name="xmax" value="$(arg  windowsize/2)" />
    <param name="ymax" value="$(arg  windowsize/2)" />
</node>
```

I have tried several combinations, all without luck. And I can't seem to find anything about it on the web...

I really do need to be able to use the 'windowsize' argument, rather than 4 x/ymax/min arguments, to support some interface I made with other nodes I made...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194368/perform-calculation-in-.launch-file/) by [koenlek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4402/koenlek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 432 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is possible starting from **Kinetic** thanks to the  `eval` keyword:

For example:

`<param name="circumference" value="$(eval 2.* 3.1415 * arg('radius'))"/>`

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2017-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [koenlek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4402/koenlek/) on 2017-01-02**:
great! That's exactly what I was looking for.

**Comment by [pranshu](https://answers.ros.org/users/57399/pranshu/) on 2023-04-15**:
Works on **Melodic** as well as **Noetic**. Tried and tested  ...
It is the correct way to do math operations in launch file